# Folders starting with a dot

Tags: windows, directory

I'm a little curious about something, I'm running Windows 7 and I had a folder called `.Net Framework` which I wanted to rename to remove the space. So I tried to call it `.Net_framework` but Windows threw an error "You must type a file name".

So there's something happening when folders start with a `.`.
I tried to call it `.NetFramework` and this wasn't accepted either.

This isn't critical in any way, anyone have any thoughts/answers on this one?

Regards,
Gog

P.S. I called it `DotNet_framework` in the end :P

Answer (score 3):

The Windows OS and NTFS have no problems with directory names starting with a dot. There are many mostly Unix based applications that use `.something` folders. 
The problem are certain Windows APIs used by `Explorer.exe` and `cmd.exe` that don't allow this.

You can use PowerShell:

```
New-Item -Type Directory -Name ".foo"
```

or

```
Move-Item  ".Net Framework" -Destination ".NetFramework"
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your comment. I'm curious about why I'm allowed to have `.Net framework` but not `.NetFramework`. I can't create this folder nor rename to this target name in explorer. Haven't tried other methods like PS or even plain old command prompt.